# Git-LFS: Push to local repository on Windows fails

Tags: git-lfs

I created a local repository on Windows which contains some Git-LFS files.  I then attempted to push that repository to another repository on the same sysem.  The **git push** failed:

```
c:\r2g-wd-git-issue-103\git-issue-103>git push origin git-issue-103-stream
Remote "origin" does not support the LFS locking API. Consider disabling it with:
  $ git config lfs.https://c////r2g-wd-git-issue-103/git-issue-103.git/info/lfs.locksverify false
batch request: ssh: Could not resolve hostname c: Name or service not known: exit status 255
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/1), 0 B | 0 B/s, done
error: failed to push some refs to 'C:/r2g-wd-git-issue-103/git-issue-103.git'
```

I suspect that Git-LFS doesn't like the Windows format of the remote origin:

```
c:\r2g-wd-git-issue-103\git-issue-103>git remote -v
origin  C:/r2g-wd-git-issue-103/git-issue-103.git (fetch)
origin  C:/r2g-wd-git-issue-103/git-issue-103.git (push)
```

Is there an alternative format I should be using for the remote origin? Or is this a different problem?  Or is this a Git-LFS bug?

I'm running **git version 2.22.0.windows.1** and **git-lfs/2.7.2 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.12.2; git 08a08ae0)** on **Windows 10 Enterprise**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a Git-LFS issue at https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3742 and got the following response:

> It is currently known that you can't use Git LFS to push to a local
>   repository unless you use a standalone transfer agent. This isn't
>   limited to Windows; it's the case everywhere.
>
> You can set up a local instance of our test server if you want, or you
>   can build your own standalone transfer agent. I'm not aware of any
>   existing ones that handle local files.